# excel vba, assigning values to variables with similar names using for next loop

Tags: vba, excel, variables, for-loop

Brand new to stackoverflow and am also quite new to programming. I am very grateful for this incredible resource. Thank you!
I have 30 TextBoxes on my Userform. TextBox1 TextBox2......TextBox30. I would like to assign values to all of them quickly using a For Next Loop. Just not too sure how.
Example:

```
For X=1 to 30
   TextBox & X.Value ="Hello"
Next X
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For x = 1 To 30
        Controls("Textbox" & x).Value = "Hello " & x
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This certainly worked. Have a great day.

Comment: Mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
For x = 1 To 30
  Sheets(1).Shapes("textbox " & x).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello"
Next x
```

Comment: The textboxes are in a userform, not on the worksheet